# XOR between string and int in Python

Tags: python, xor

How to do a XOR operation between a string with an integer in Python?
Below is what I type:

```
x = 'a'
y = x^5
print(y)
```

It show me this error: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ^: 'str' and 'int'`

Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand why you'd want to do that...?

Comment: What is your expected outcome? Are you really wondering how to xor the hexadecimal number `0xa` with `5`?

Comment: What do you expect e.g. `"fart" ^ 5` to do?

Answer (score 2):

Convert the string (char) to `ord`:

```
y = ord('a')^5
```

Comment: The `ord()` method returns an integer representing the Unicode code point of the given Unicode character. For example `'5'` [is](https://ascii.cl/) 53. It will convert your char to integer value.

Answer (score 2):

`ord` gives you the unicode value of a character. A character's binary representation is the binary of its ASCII/Unicode value.

```
x = 'a'
y = ord(x) ^ 5

print(y)
>>> 100
```

Using `bin()` to check the binary representation of 100, we see 100 is 0b1100100.

Of course this only works on single characters and not strings.